# Usp_updateXXXX is throwing has too many arguements

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, exception, stored-procedures

We were working on deadlock issue and went to a solution where we are catching the deadlock exception and resubmitting for 6 times. users are happy that they didnt get any errors but a new error thrown after 2 hours moved to production with the below error "Usp_updateXXXX is throwing has too many arguements" . This issue is happening whenever the app encounters deaadlock exception.

Please find the code snippet below 
{
            //msg = string.Empty;

```
        SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(Conn);
        SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter _adp = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);
        _cmd.Connection = _con;
        bool isDeadlock = false;
        int reTry = 0;
        //Check for Deadlock and retry for 6 times to send the same request
        do
        {
            msg = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                _con.Open();
                _cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                _cmd.CommandText = "usp_UpdateXXXX";
         //Assign the command parametrs                         
                _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                   isDeadlock = false;                    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if ((ex.Message.Contains("was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim")) || (ex.Message.Contains("deadlock")) || (ex.Message.Contains("Transaction (Process ID")))
                {

                    isDeadlock = true;
                    Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    reTry++;

                }
                else
                {
                    msg = ex.Message;
                    isDeadlock = false;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        } while (reTry < 6 && isDeadlock == true);
```

Can any one help me where is the code bug which causing to throw the exception.

Regards
Prashant

Comment: `//Assign the command parametrs`  - Does this procedure work normally? Can you add the actual statements for this part?

Comment: Hi Shree .. It worked fine before adding the loop and now its not working when ever it encounters deadlock issue.. Sorry I cant add the paramaters

Comment: Don't sleep with the connection open. You risk exhausting the thread pool or worse.

Comment: Yeah.. But I had no other option.. As per my knowledge Opening the connection is again is time consuming.. Please suggest me if I can modify the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue happened because of the looping used. Actually when the exception happens it is again going to call the loop without clearing the existing parameters hence its adding the new parameters .

To resolve this issue I cleared the parameters once its in the exception section.

```
try{
     //statements here
   }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if ((ex.Message.Contains("was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen              as                   the deadlock victim")) || (ex.Message.Contains("deadlock")) || (ex.Message.Contains("Transaction (Process ID")))
            {
                   //used below statement
                command.Parameters.Clear() ;

                isDeadlock = true;
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                reTry++;

            }
            else
            {
                msg = ex.Message;
                isDeadlock = false;
            }
        }
```

This resolved my prob.

Regards
Prashant